# Question on Group Presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it true that $\mathbb{Z}^{2}\ast\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ has a group presentation: $\langle a,b,c,d|ab=ba,cd=dc\rangle$. If not, what is the correct group presentation. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: @Andrea: maybe you should post that as an answer? (perhaps with some notes why)

Comment: @MANI your edit had completely changed the meaning of the question. $\ast$ and $\times$ mean different things here (look up "free product" and "direct product"). (And no, this is not the free abelian group.) I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: @user1729 Sir, actually I saw it later and wants to reedit the question but due to some technical error I was not able to do so. sorry for that mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\,\{a,b\}\,\,,\,\,\{c,d\}\,$ be the (free abelian) generators of the first and second factors, resp., in the free product. Clearly, $\,ab=ba\,\,,\,\,cd=dc\,$ are relations in each of these factors resp. and, thus, also in the free product, and there can't be any more relations as both factors are free *abelian* groups in those generators.

You may want to check theorem 11.53 in Rotman's "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups", 4th Ed.